# SQL Server Returns error on geography column

Tags: sql-server, service-application

I have seen questions regarding this but not exactly my scenario:

I have created a service. It runs on one server that is also a web server. It looks at a remote server running SQL Server to gather data to run.

When getting data from one of the tables, there is a column with a geography data type. In the web application that is running, no problems getting this table as `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` is referenced.

A service running on the Web server creates and error:

> DataReader.GetFieldType(22) returned null.

When doing a select statement on this remote machine even the same dll is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Very Strange. The query is a very basic "Select * from ..... where ....."

I kept searching and found a post suggesting setting the reference to the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll from the following folder:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared

I made the change. Copied the recompiled service with the new dll to the installed folder on the web server and now it completes without the error.

I didn't create the original code so I am not sure where the original dll reference came from.